# To display other JSON objects based on their ID

Tags: typescript, angular6

I have 2 JSON files called `teachers` and `sessions` as shown below:

**teachers**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Teacher 1",
    "sessionId": "02"
  },
  {
    "name": "Teacher 2",
    "sessionId": "03"
  },
  {
    "name": "Teacher 3",
    "sessionId": "01"
  }
]
```

**sessions**

```
    [
    {
        "id":"01",
        "name": "Session 01"
    },
    {
        "id":"02",
        "name": "Session 02"
    },
    {
        "id":"03",
        "name": "Session 03"
    },
    {
        "id":"004",
        "name": "Session 04"
    }
]
```

I want display the session for the particular `teacher` like this:

[image]

But i couldn't, Below is my component CODE:

**HTML**

```
<h4>Teachers</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let teacher of teachers">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{teacher.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Assigned Session: </td>
        <li *ngFor="let session of selectedSession">{{session?.name}}</li>
    </tr>   
    <hr>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from './contacts.service';
import{ ISessions,ITeachers} from '../models/app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  teachers: ITeachers[];
  sessions: ISessions[];
  public selectedSession: ISessions[];

  constructor(private myService: ContactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getTeachers()
      .subscribe(res => this.teachers = res);
       this.myService.getSession()
      .subscribe(res => this.sessions = res);

    for (const teacher of this.teachers)  {
      if (teacher.sessionId) {
        this.getSessionById(teacher.sessionId);
     }
    }

  }


public getSessionById(sessionId: string){
 this.selectedSession = this.sessions ? this.sessions.filter((x: ISessions) => x.id === sessionId) : [];
 console.log(this.selectedSession);
}

}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-3knmwj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle result like this:

```
this.result = this.teachers.map(teacher => 
({...this.sessions.find(p => teacher.sessionId === p.id), teacher}));
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-join-object

Updated:

I update query to group teacher and sessions they teach, may be 1 teacher teach many session.

```
 this.result = this.teachers.map(teacher => 
({session: this.sessions.filter(p => teacher.sessionId === p.id), teacher}));
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-join-object-2

Comment: Can you solve this? **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803714/how-to-close-bootstrap-4-model-by-calling-a-function-in-typescript**

Answer (score 1):

You should never subscribe within a subscribe. Better use zip, forkJoin or similar. You can then reduce the data and get grouped how you want it

```
zip(this.myService.getTeachers(), this.myService.getSession())
  .pipe(
    flatMap(([t, s]) => {
      return of(t.reduce((a, b) => {
        a[b.sessionId] = (a[b.sessionId] || b);
        a[b.sessionId].sessions = s.filter(e => e.id === b.sessionId);
        return a;
      }, {}));
    })
  ).subscribe(e => this.teachers = e);
```