# How to close bootstrap 4 model by calling a function in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using bootstrap 4 modal followed by the **[example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)**

Below is the **template** code:

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Open
    </button>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
          </div>

           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  (click)="save()">Save</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here on clicking the `open` button i am opening dialog window,On clicking `save` button i will call `save()` method.In **.ts** i have written some conditions inside `save` method like this:

```
 save(){
  if(condition){
    ......don't close the modal....
  } else{
   ......close the modal....
   }
 }
```

How can i close the `modal` by calling the `save()` method in `typescript`?

**[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjwtqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: u r opening dialog box because  both id are maching that's why ur modal is opening

Comment: @PGH the better way to use bootstrap modal is to create a reusable modal component . if you use default bootstrap modal means you have to rely on jquery which is bad news , angular and jquery should not be used together. So  here is a sample to create reusable modal component : : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another solution without trick on close button.

First step you need install `jquery` and `bootstrap` by `npm` command.

Second you need add `declare var $ : any;` in component (**important step**)

And use can use `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` on `onSave()` method

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to do this in Angular/Typescript is to use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

First import `ViewChild` :

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Add this line in your component, with the selector of your choice :

```js
@ViewChild('myModalClose') modalClose;
```

Add the tag `myModalClose` in your html (here we target the close button) :

```html
<!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" #myModalClose class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
  ...
```

In your `save()` method :

```js
this.modalClose.nativeElement.click();
```

---

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugwb1a)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-bootstrap alternatively to control all this in your component class.
[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api)

In typescript component code you need to inject NgbActiveModal in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal){}
```

and then in save method, you can just close it:

```
save(){
if(condition){
    ......don't close the modal....
  } else{
   this.activeModal.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: From where i need to import `NgbActiveModal`?

Comment: I think I got confused with bootstrap. But in our project we use ng-bootstrap. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: I am not using `ng-bootstrap`

Comment: @PGH the better way to use bootstrap modal is to create a reusable modal component . if you use default bootstrap modal means you have to rely on jquery which is bad news , angular and jquery should not be used together. So  here is a sample to create reusable modal component : : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360691/how-to-make-a-modal-reusable-in-angular-2/56559002#56559002

Answer (score 0):

Use Ngx bootstrap https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

here is the common component for ngx bootstap modal.

```
<!-- Contains insides of a host element e.g. button text or link text -->
<ng-content></ng-content>
<!-- Dialog box content -->
<ng-template #modalWrapper>
  <!-- Header template -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title pull-left">{{ modalTitle }}</h3>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Body template that consist of provided template reference content -->
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="modalContent"></ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Component.ts

```
export class AppModalComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  /** Template Reference that is displayed as part of dialog box content */
  @Input('app-modal') public modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;
  /** Title of the dialog box */
  @Input() public modalTitle: string = '';
  /** Defines if modal is open */
  @Input() public isOpenByDefault: boolean = false;
  /** Modal reference */
  public modalRef: BsModalRef;
  /** Content config object */
  @Input() public config: ModalOptions = {};
  /** Event on modal open */
  @Output() public open = new EventEmitter<void>();
  /** Event on modal close */
  @Output() public close = new EventEmitter<void>();
  /** Wrapper template reference */
  @ViewChild('modalWrapper') public content: TemplateRef<any>;

  /** Injects modalService to manipulate modals */
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.config) {
      this.modalService.config = changes.config.currentValue;
    }
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isOpenByDefault ? this.openModal() : this.closeModal();
  }

  /** On click of host element opens a modal with provided modal content */
  @HostListener('click')
  public openModal(): void {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.content, this.config);
    this.open.emit();
  }

  /** On click of close button closes the modal */
  public closeModal(): void {
    if (this.modalRef) {
      this.modalRef.hide();
      this.close.emit();
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
<button [app-modal]="template" modalTitle="Modal Title" [isOpenByDefault]="false" #modalRef>Open modal</button>
<ng-template #template>
  <h4>Hello world</h4>
</ng-template>
```